# How go get custom value of SIP header in FreeSWITCH SIP BYE

Tags: c, freeswitch

I want to get value of **Custom-Order** in SIP BYE header. I've tried to use ${sip_bye_h_Custom-Order} but it's empty, because have no **X-** prefix before header name.

I can edit freeswitch **sofia.c** for support get value of **Custom-Order** in SIP INVITE.
FreeSWITCH version is 1.10.8

```
// sofia_handle_sip_i_invite() is just work for invite header
} else if (!strcasecmp(un->un_name, "CALLED_DID")) {
    switch_channel_set_variable(channel, "called_did", un->un_value);
    **// add below code**
} else if (!strcasecmp(un->un_name, "Custom-Order"))
    switch_channel_set_variable(channel, "custom_order", un->un_value);
}
```

How can I edit 'sofia.c' for support get value of 'Custom-Order' in SIP BYE. Is need to edit sofia_handle_sip_i_bye() ?

Is there any other method to extract custom value from SIP BYE header?